# Questions about C++ iterators

Tags: c++

In C++, why can't we use '>' or '<' to compare InputIterators, ForwardIterators and BidirectionalIterators? However, we can compare RandomAccessIterators with '>' or '<', for example std::vector. What is the reason behind this?

Also, why can't we cout iterators' content? such as "cout << itr << endl;" wouldn't work. What is the reason behind this? Iterators are a lot like pointers, but we can cout pointers but not iterators, why?

In general, what is the intrinsic difference between iterators and pointers? I used to think they are similar, but I guess I have to understand this in order to get to the next level of understanding c++.

Question#2: Thank you all for awesome answers. I have one more question in regards to iterators.
Why c++ prints out something like "50397953" when the iterator goes out of bounds? Shouldn't it be printing something like NULL or '\0' ?

Comment: How long do you thing it would take to evaluate `itr1 < itr2` for two forward iterators?

Comment: Thanks Beta. This is a natural answer!

Answer (score 5):

`std::list<T>` has bidirectional iterators and it doesn't make any sense to require them to be comparable. It's not even clear how it would be possible to implement `std::list<T>` in order to be compliant with such a requirement. However, since random access iterators support subtraction, it is obvious that we can compare them.

Why can't we print the value of an iterator? In general, it's up to the author whether to support such an operation. Many iterators are basically just implemented as pointers or wrappers around pointers---providing `operator<<` for them wouldn't give the user any benefit they couldn't get by simply printing out the address of the object pointed to.

As for the difference between iterators and pointers, pointers to objects are a specific kind of random access iterator, but iterators can also be of class type so long as they satisfy the iterator requirements.

Comment: Thanks Brian. But why wouldn't providing operator << give the user any benefit? Isn't the memory address something programmers examines all the time?

Comment: @Thenewstockton You can just `std::cout << &*it` if you want that. In my experience, it isn't useful often enough to provide a shorthand.

Comment: @Thenewstockton in my experience, while doing things like you suggest – providing operator overloads for bespoke iterators – often seems like it will be more useful than it will be in the long run. This is because any tactical syntactic innovations you add end up working against the semantic strategy of the iterator convention: there are few syntax additions to [the notion of an iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) that don’t, in my opinion, have to work against the overarching concept, which as has been mentioned above is: “a generalization of pointers”. Basically.

Answer (score 3):

There's both a rigid, formal explanation, and a practical one.

## The rigid, formal explanation

Because that's how it's specified in C++.

## The practical explanation

A vector is always stored in contiguous memory, by definition. An iterator is, more or less a pointer. Therefore, by comparing the actual underlying memory addresses it is possible to define which pointer is "less" or "greater" than the other pointer.

On the other hand, each element in a list, or a set, could be stored anywhere. Each element is instantiated independently. An iterator for one particular element in the list could be referencing a numerically lesser memory location than a different iterator for another element in the same list, but the actual element could be after the other element, in the actual list. Given two iterators in a list it cannot be immediately determined which one is closer to the beginning or to the end of the list. Note that inserting and removing elements in a list does not invalidate existing list iterators, because each element in the list is instantiated independently.

The practical reason why you cannot use iterators with `operator<<` on a `std::ostream` is because, of course, this overload is not defined. Note that you can always do the following, instead:

```
cout << &*itr << endl;
```

This will format the actual memory address of the referenced element. But this is of dubious use anyway. It's mostly meaningless.

Comment: Thanks Sam. But why wouldn't STL define the overload ? I know one can print out the address by using &*itr. However, isn't it natural to support "cout << itr << endl;" ? I think it has to do with the difference between pointers and iterators, but I don't really know why? Please help!

Comment: @Thenewstockton: Why do you think it would be natural? Doesn't seem so to me.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley   Well, this is what I think:  you can do "cout << ptr << end;" , so it is natural to do "cout << itr << endl;" but this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I will not answer the first part of your question because I agree with what had been said, but I will answer you the other two parts adding some details. I am starting from the easiest part to explain.

> In general, what is the intrinsic difference between iterators and pointers? I used to think they are similar, but I guess I have to understand this in order to get to the next level of understanding c++.

Iterators are generalization of pointers.

You can also look at that [iterator implementation on github](https://gist.github.com/jeetsukumaran/307264)

> Also, why can't we cout iterators' content? such as "cout << itr << endl;" wouldn't work. What is the reason behind this? Iterators are a lot like pointers, but we can cout pointers but not iterators, why?

So, what is happening inside, as I understand, is that iterator is a class which has a field storing a pointer to an item. The '*' operator is overwritten and returns the value that is stored at the pointers address.